# Unable to submit keys using selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Following is the code which im trying to run

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os
import time

#Create a new firefox session
browser=webdriver.Firefox()
browser.maximize_window()


#navigate to app's homepage
browser.get('http://demo.magentocommerce.com/')

#get searchbox and clear and enter details.
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href='/search']").click()
search=browser.find_element_by_class_name('search-input')

search.click()
time.sleep(5)
search.click()
search.send_keys('phones'+Keys.RETURN)
```

However, im unable to submit the phones using send_keys.
Am i going wrong somewhere?

Secondly is it possible to always use x-path to locate an element and not rely on id/class/css-selections etc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input element you are interested in has the `search_query` class name. To make it work without using hardcoded `time.sleep()` delays, use an [Explicit Wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits) and *wait for the search input element to be visible* before sending keys to it. Working code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

browser.get('http://demo.magentocommerce.com/')

browser.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href='/search']").click()

search = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "search-query")))
search.send_keys("phones" + Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: Thanks!! This works as expected.
Could you explain the working of the last two lines ?

Comment: @abhisheknair the line before the last one is the key to the solution here - it both waits for the element matching a locator to become visible (make sure you follow the link to the docs and understand this part) and returns it. Then, we send the search query to the located input element and the `RETURN` which submits the form in our case. Hope that clears things up.